# Having, holding, giving, and throwing parties

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-difference

What is the difference between "hold a party", "have a party", "give a party" and "throw a party"?

Is there any difference in meaning? Can we use them interchangeably?

Could you provide some examples (if any exist) where we can't replace one by another?

Comment: In the context of *I am going to host a party.* they are all equivalent. A colloquial reader/listener would understand your intent with any of the options.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent agreed. *You have a party tonight* is different from *You give...* and so on.

Comment: The whole group can be the subject of *hold* or *have*, but only the host can *give* or *throw* a party.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think they're all pretty much interchangeable. As I tried to think of an exception, I wondered if *throw* would be a bit more appropriate for a wild party, and less appropriate for a less festive occasion. However, I found plenty of instances of "throw an office party" on Google, enough to convince me that *throw* doesn't necessarily imply "wild and crazy."

One additional verb you could use is "host": *We are going to host a party on the 11th*.

For what it's worth, [here's an Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hold+a+party%2Cthrow+a+party%2Cgive+a+party%2Chost+a+party%2Chave+a+party&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chold%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrow%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgive%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chost%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20party%3B%2Cc0), but there's nothing too remarkable there.

Answer (score 1):

"Have a party" and "throw a party" are the same to me, with "throw" being a bit more casual. "Hold a party" to my mind involves a venue that is not my home - "I am going to hold a party at a restaurant or banquet hall."