# Can I say "I am holding a party" when the party is happening?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

It is not the tense that I an worried about. It is the meaning of the verb “**hold**”. “**Hold**” means “**organize**”.

I think “**to hold a party**” means “**to lay out chairs, table and put other decoration etc**”

So, “I am holding the party” means “*I am laying out chairs and putting decoration etc*”.

After everything is in place. The party is not being **held**.

The “**party is being held**” must happen before the party starts

Can I say "**I am holding a party**" when the party is happening and guests are celebrating?

Comment: "hold a party"  just means to "have a party". Can you say: I'm having a party? What do you think? And it has zero do with all the accoutrements for it.

Answer (score 1):

According to a [previous question here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31955/having-holding-giving-and-throwing-parties), holding a party doesn't necessarily mean just organizing the party in the sense of placing chairs and putting decoration. And, going by the dictionary, [hold](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold) can mean "cause to happen" rather than merely "organize". So you "holding a party" means "causing a party to happen" - that covers much more than just decorating and putting chairs out.

Answer (score 1):

I think your intuition is correct—I would **not** say "I am holding a party" when the party is actively going on.

I would say "I'm hosting a party" or "There is a party happening at my house." In both cases I would probably also add "right now" or "at the moment" at the end of each sentence to make it very clear.

Comment: To hold a party is formal, but one can say it, of course. "What are you doing tonight or right?" I'm holding or having or hosting a party for colleagues from work. The OP's error is related to thinking that holding a party means putting out chairs or tables for it. That is the **mistake**.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that particular wording would generally come before the actual party. However, you could say that during the party itself if, for example, you get a phone call from someone you'd normally talk to but because of the party you don't really have time for it right that moment (although there are plenty of more normal ways of saying it).